# How to find minimum and maximum values in Column B based on a specific string in column A?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of items in Column A and have corresponding year and month values in Column B and C respectively. I am looking to find the minimum and maximum year in Column B (based on specific value in Column A), then find the corresponding month in Column C (only for max and min value) and then generate and fill in a Start and End date in Column E and F respectively. 
E.g. IF @Item = Laptop THEN FIND MIN,MAX of @YEAR and THEN FIND adjacent value in @Month. Finally formulate and display a date accordingly. 
Could i achieve this using a formula or is it out of scope and is better achieved using a macro?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Start date, in E2:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,DATE(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$1000/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,$C$1:$C$1000/(($A$1:$A$1000=A2)*($B$1:$B$1000 = AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$1:$B$1000/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1))),1),1),"")
```

And for the end date in F2:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,EOMONTH(DATE(AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$1000/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$1:$C$1000/(($A$1:$A$1000=A2)*($B$1:$B$1000 = AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$1:$B$1000/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1))),1),1),0),"")
```

Then copy down the desired rows.

The aggregate function was introduced in 2010 so it will not work in excel 2007 or earlier.

[image]

I over thought they can be simplified to:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AGGREGATE(15,6,DATE($B$1:$B$1000,$C$1:$C$1000,1)/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1),"")
```

And:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,EOMONTH(DATE($B$1:$B$1000,$C$1:$C$1000,1),0)/($A$1:$A$1000=A2),1),"")
```

Thanks to @Jerry for showing a more succinct method.

Comment: Thanks for the formula! Am I just looking to replace the string "Laptop" with the cell (e.g. A1) instead, if I am just looking to apply the formula across the entire range?

Comment: @user1266515 see edit.  Put in the E2 and F2 and copy down it will put blank in the proper rows and the values in the first row with a new Item.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that I think should work for any version of Excel, and thanks to the comment from @ScottCarver you can now copy it down and it will put the dates on the first row of each Item:

Enter this in E2 as an array formula and then copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,MIN(IF(A:A=A2,DATE(B:B,C:C,1))),"")
```

Enter this in F2 as an array formula and then copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,MAX(IF(A:A=A2,DATE(B:B,C:C+1,0))),"")
```

Because these are array formulas you need to press control-shift-enter instead of just enter.  After they are entered they will be surrounded by { } to indicate that they are array formulas.

Original Answer:

Here is something that I think should work for any version of Excel, but you can't copy it down - you have to enter one separately for every Item.  If you really want them spread out so that the dates are on the row of the first occurance of the Item (like in your screenshot) then this won't really work for you.

For the start date of the Laptop Item:

```
=MIN(IF(A:A="Laptop",DATE(B:B,C:C,1)))
```

For the end date of the Laptop Item:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A="Laptop",DATE(B:B,C:C+1,0)))
```

These are array formulas so you need to press control-shift-enter instead of just enter.  After they are entered they will be surrounded by { } to indicate that they are array formulas.

Comment: I just get a 0 when I enter this in the Start Date Cell. Trying to run through the calculation steps

Comment: @user1266515 make sure you enter it as an array formula.  You also might need to format the cell as a date.

Comment: So once again I over thought. You can do the copy down, Just use `=IF(A2<>A1,MIN(IF(A:A=A2,DATE(B:B,C:C,1))),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner  You are so right.  Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: I hope you don't mind I married your approach with the aggregate function.